How to solve not changing page when activate a tab in sidebar
I am new to HTML and JS and have this dashboard with a sidebar but I could not change the page when I click on next tab, for example it shows empty page when I click on analytics. Please help me so I can add my charts in analytics tab and other tabs.
I use chart js for charts and have styles.css file


// Function to change content
function changeContent(tabName) {
  // Hide all tab contents
  var tabPanes = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane');
  tabPanes.forEach(pane => {
    pane.classList.remove('active');
    pane.style.display = 'none';
  });

  // Show the clicked tab
  var activePane = document.getElementById(tabName);
  if (activePane) {
    activePane.classList.add('active');
    activePane.style.display = 'block';

    // If it's the analytics tab and it's empty, load the content
    if (tabName === 'analytics' && activePane.innerHTML.trim() === '') {
      loadAnalyticsContent();
    }
  }

  // Remove active class from all buttons
  var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-button');
  tabButtons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('active'));

  // Add active class to the clicked button
  var activeButton = document.querySelector(`.tab-button[data-tab="${tabName}"]`);
  if (activeButton) {
    activeButton.classList.add('active');
  }
}

// Tab functionality
const tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar a');

tabButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const tabId = this.getAttribute('data-tab');
    if (tabId) {
      changeContent(tabId);
    }
  });
});
 <div class="sidebar">
 <a href="#" class="tab-button active" data-tab="dashboard" onclick="changeContent('dashboard')">
                    <span class="material-icons-sharp">
                        dashboard
                    </span>
                    <h3>Dashboard</h3>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="tab-button" data-tab="users" 
                    onclick="changeContent('users')">
                    <span class="material-icons-sharp">
                        person_outline
                    </span>
                    <h3>Users</h3>

<main>
  <div id="dashboard" class="tab-pane active">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="analyse">
      <div class="sales">
        <div class="status">
          <div class="info">
            <h3>Total Sales</h3>
            <h1>$65,024</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="progresss">
            <svg>
                                <circle cx="38" cy="38" r="36"></circle>
                            </svg>
            <div class="percentage">
              <p>+81%</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="users" class="tab-pane">
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <!-- Users content -->
      </div>
      <div id="history" class="tab-pane">
        <h1>History</h1>
        <!-- History content -->
      </div>
      <div id="analytics" class="tab-pane">
        <h2>Analytics Dashboard</h2>
        <div id="date-range-picker">
          <input type="date" id="start-date">
          <input type="date" id="end-date">
          <button id="apply-date-range">Apply</button>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-container">
          <canvas id="user-activity-chart"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-container">
          <canvas id="revenue-chart"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
</main>




You don't have any elements with class=sidebar in your html here.

Could you describe what debugging you have tried and also make sure your snippet is complete enough to show the problem. At the moment, nothing happens as nothing has had a click event associated with it.

I add the class = sidebar in there, it has all the IDs that I write, I try to use console to see what is had may go wrong, but everything's looks like working fine

If you were to log the tabName in changeContent() you would see that the tabName is "users" when you click "analytics". The Users section has no content.

Your anchor tag (<a...>) for the Users isn't closed, so the entirety of the rest of the code is part of that link.

You may like first to put your code through a validator, e.g. https://validator.w3.org/ and alter the code you have shown accordingly. Please try it, check there are no errors through your browser devtools inspect facility and ensure the the snippet still shows the problem.
